# How to Fit a decay exponential function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve, exponential

I have to fit the dots, results of measurements, by an exponential function on Matlab. My profesor asked me to use only

- fminsearch
- polyval
- polyfit

One of them or both. I have to find the parameters a and b (the value) which are fitting it.

There is the lines I wrote :

```
x=[1:10:70]
y=[0:10:70]
x=[12.5,11.8,10.8,10.9,6.5,6.2,6.1,5.423,4.625]
y=[0,0.61,1.3,1.4,14.9,18.5,20.1,29.7,58.2]
xlabel('Conductivité')
ylabel('Inductance')
```

The function has the form `a*e^(-b*x) +c`

Comment: I don’t see a question in your post. You are just telling us what **you** need to work on. Please be specific about the question you want people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well polyfit and polyval are only usefull for working with polynomials. So you would have to write a minimization problem of the form min(f(x)).

```
functionToMinimize = @(pars, x, y)(norm(pars(1).*exp(-pars(2).*x) - y));
targetFunctionForFminseardch = @(pars)(functionToMinimize(pars, x, y));
minPars = fminsearch(targetFunctionForFminseardch, [0, 1])
```

Read up on anonymous functions and the use of vector norms if you have questions how to construct such a minimization problem.

Your code also has some flaws. Why are you defining x and y twice when you only want to use the actual measured data?

Comment: If you take the logarithm you get polynomials.

Comment: or you could use `fit` and `fittype` as in [https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/exponential.html]

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right! Using log before running the fminsearch should help, since its only a linear regression problem so fminsearch would be quite a bit of overkill. Thanks for the input!